# Ant - Escaping escape characters

Tags: regex, ant

If I have lots of entries in a text file like this:

```
&ldquo;AAA&rdquo;
&ldquo;BBB&rdquo;
&ldquo;CCCCC&rdquo;
```

that I want to turn into this:

```
<b>AAA</b>
<b>BBB</b>
<b>CCCCCC</b>
```

How do I deal with escaping the escape characters in something like this?

```
<replaceregexp byline="true" flags="gis">
<regexp pattern="&ldquo;(.*)&rdquo;
<substitution expression="&lt;b&gt;\1&lt;/b&gt;"/>
<fileset dir=".">
<include name="*.xml"/>
</fileset>
</replaceregexp>
```

If I write it like that it's obviously reading the & and ; not the way I want it to, but I've been reading trying to figure out how to have it search for those as literal text and can't figure it out. I've tried wrapping it in a CDATA tag but that didn't work. I read some other responses here, tried `&amp;amp;` for the ampersands, but don't know what to use for the semicolon.

Comment: You shoudn't have to escape `;`. A semicolon on its own doesn't have any special meaning in either XML or regular expressions. I also don't see why you'd need to escape `&` twice -- `&amp;` should be sufficient.

Comment: One of the things I just read suggested &amp;amp;, I had already tried just `&amp;` so gave it a shot. Just wanted to list all of the things I'd tried, seems like it should just be `&amp;` to me also. Will keep fiddling with it.

Comment: pdw: Okay that did it, thanks. Was simpler than I had thought.

Answer (score 1):

Okay it was simpler than I thought, had just read too many things. Solution:

```
<replaceregexp byline="true">
<regexp pattern="&amp;ldquo;(.*)&amp;rdquo;"/>
<substitution expression="&lt;b&gt;\1&lt;/b&gt;"/>
<fileset dir=".">
<include name="*.xml"/>
</fileset>
</replaceregexp>
```

Thanks to pdw.